# How do you keep up to date of the latest UX trends?

Tags: ux-field, ux-designer, guidelines, news

I am new in UI/UX and I have been seeing design systems suggested by many articles and design trends to know about. I was wondering where people are getting all these ideas or news from? Is there some sort of website or group I could go to to stay up to date?

Comment: UI/UX doesn't exist. Other than that, this is one for the groups you're looking for, but you could also try doing a Google search for whatever specialty you have.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I use [UX Collective](https://uxdesign.cc/), but [NN Group](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/) are the OGs of UX. From what I remember, one of the founders coined the word UX, and already I see they have an article up on psychology in UX. Very, very good place to start.

But as for design systems and the like, UX Collective would be the place.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst trends are usually very big in other design areas, UX is a bit more stable as the approach is usually much more scientific than, say, graphic design. There's three things playing a part on UX Trends:

- Different products follow a specific approach for solving things through design, creating new patterns easily recognizable by users which are then reproduced.
- Widely-used patterns are discredited through study and research and used less and less.
- There are new findings in Psychology, HCI, etc. which push us into other directions previously unexplored or not considered. *Have you noticed corners have gotten rounder? [There's a reason for it](https://uxmovement.com/thinking/why-rounded-corners-are-easier-on-the-eyes/).*

I'm afraid I can't point you in the direction of quality content related to what I stated above as it's usually very sparse (as it's usually kept behind closed doors by the companies who fund the research), but I always share [evernote.design](https://evernote.design) with people new to the field, as it usually provides a big enough playground for you to start exploring a lot of UX/UI Resources.

I wish you the best on this new journey of yours!

Comment: While I agree with the gist of your answer, your first link is about Contour Bias, which is not exactly new ;)

Comment: Haha, that's a sharp observation @Devin. You are entirely correct! It was scientifically identified in 2006, if I'm not mistaken. The fact that squared buttons were better rendered on late-century computing systems and how people had gotten so used to them probably has played a big part in designers integrating them.